# Allow higher values “for” (vs “than”) entry counts

Tags: meaning, phrases

I got question reading a journal...

> Studies  have shown  that  occupancy  count  can  be  used  to
> complement  entry  counts  and  **allow  higher  values  for  such
> entry  counts**.

I'm so confused of the phrase I marked above.
Does the 'for' in the phrase mean 'than', so it means that 'occupancy count values are higher than entry counts'?
Or it just mean that 'the occupancy value enables entry counts to have higher values'?

cf) entry count: number  of  aircraft **entering**  an airspace  in  one hour.

occupancy count: number  of  aircraft  **within**  an  airspace in 5 minutes. (=number of aircraft on the frequency in 5 minutes (e.g. 20 aircraft at the same time)). An aircraft is considered to be on the frequency from the time at the airspace entry point until it reaches the exit point.

Comment: If the sentence is from an article about aircraft, _please explain this_. It's not easy to tell what it means out of context.

Comment: It means that entry counts can be higher than they otherwise would have been.

Comment: In this context, "for" similar to "of".